# AWS Glue: How to reduce the number of DPUs for an ETL job

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

AWS Glue documentation regarding pricing reads:

> A Glue ETL job requires a minimum of 2 DPUs. By default, AWS Glue
>   allocates 10 DPUs to each ETL job. You are billed $0.44 per DPU-Hour
>   in increments of 1 minute, rounded up to the nearest minute, with a
>   10-minute minimum duration for each ETL job.

I want to reduce the number of DPUs allocated to my ETL job. I searched for this option in Glue console. But I didn't find it. Can you please let me know how do I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To reduce the number of DPU, please go to AWS glue jobs console. Select the job and under action Edit the job. Under "Script libraries and job parameters", you should see "Concurrent DPUs per job run". You can provide an integer value to increase or reduce the number of DPUs.

Comment: Is there a way to do this via the SDK?